# wpf devexpress change theme move position of controls

Tags: wpf, position, devexpress, themes

In wpf, devexpress,when The theme effect on forms,causes change theme position of controls
in run time ,and it causes moving controls from the position of design time.
Why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by position of controls? Their theme also changes the style of various controls of theirs, so their appearance (including things like padding and margin) will change affecting the overall layout of your app.

If you want the theme to only change the colors of your controls then you will have to create your own custom themes using their [Theme Editor](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Themes/theme-editor.xml) tool (not an easy task though). Also you are better off asking this question in their help forums, they are quite helpful and often come up with good solutions.